# Elasticsearch - Java API for indexing

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I have a folder containing JSON documents. I want to read all the files inside the directory and index each file. I tried this:

```
public void indexDocuments() {
    String path = "/path/to/file/";

    List<File> files = Files.walk(Paths.get(path)).filter(Files::isRegularFile).map(Path::toFile).collect(Collectors.toList());

    for(int i=0; i<files.size(); i++) {
        IndexResponse response = client.prepareIndex("test", "test").setSource(files.get(i)).execute().actionGet();
    }
}
```

but it won't work. It says `The method map is not applicable for the arguments(Path::toFile)`

I searched for this problem and found the sample codes exactly like this. I can't figure out the problem.

Any suggestions would be excellent.

Comment: The line which is problematic for you works exactly as expected in a clean environment, therefore the problem must be somewhere in the code you don't show us. Perchance, have you imported any other "File" or "Path" class, so that File does not denote java.io.File or Path is something different than java.nio.file.Path?

Comment: There was a problem with the packages. I used "Path" and "File" classes before this part and that part automatically imported different packages. Changed it and the error is gone. Thanks for the tip @mtj